# Unable to use Searchable in laravel model

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-scout

I am trying to use Laravel Scout Searchable into my model but it gives me an error

```
Undefined type 'Laravel\Scout\Searchable'.
```

I have already included

```
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
```

in the code.  Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

I have followed the documentation as is until this point.

Answer (score 3):

After a little bit of tinkering around I found the answer myself.

The error was produced by PHP intelliphense plugin of VS Code. It seems there is a problem with a version of the plugin I used. I downgraded my version one step and now it detects everything correctly.

Comment: Downgrading from 1.8.2 to 1.8.0 fixed it for me. Thanks!